# Need to create a picklist that displays the number of projects for the same object name

Tags: apex, visualforce

There is an object called site that has the same name for 2 different projects.
I need to create a picklist/any visualforce page that displays the number of projects.

We have created a Site master which is a lookup relationhip to site.

```
public List<SelectOption> getPicklistProjects()
{
  // This displays how may Site of the same are present
  List <Site__c> PicklistProjects = [ SELECT Count(Id), Name FROM Site__c Group By Name Having Count(Id) > 1 ];


   // This displays the number of SiteMasters for each site with that project.
   List <Site__c> PicklistProjects1 = [SELECT Site_Master__r.Name ,Project__r.Name FROM Site__c ];

   return PicklistProjects;
}


<apex:pageBlock title="Select Projects">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!PicklistProjects}" var="item">
            <apex:column value="{!item.name}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>

<!--
<apex:selectList id="Projects" value="Select Projects"
         size="1" required="true">
  <apex:selectOptions value="{!PicklistProjects}"/>
</apex:selectList>
-->formatted text here
'
```

I get an error on the Query editor:""Field must be grouped or aggregated: Name
""

```
SELECT Site_Master__r.Name name1,Project__r.Name name2, Site__c.Name ,Count(Id)  
  FROM Site__c Group By Site__c.Name Having Count(Id) > 1
```

This should display the SiteMaster name that contains different projects.

Comment: And what did you try so far ?

Comment: I have seen a similar problem with the query editor; try adding an alias to the `Site__c.name` as in `...site__c.name name0 ...`